# Does German language have "possessive apostrophe"?

Tags: history, spelling, possessive

Does (did) German have something like what they call [possessive apostrophe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Possessive_apostrophe)
 in English? 
If not, what does the role of it in German language?

For example:

> This is my father's hat.
>   My best friend's husband.

Comment: Well, we *do* have the [Deppenapostroph](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophitis)...

Comment: @Jan: Doh! I should had searched it in Wikipedia's German version.

Comment: I've just read in that article that interestingly enough, we actually had the possessive apostrophe for some foreign words until about 2 centuries ago, even though it's no longer correct today. I never knew that...

Comment: @Jan: What about posting an answer? ;-)

Comment: Whoops, I actually misread that from the article. Disregard my comment about the foreign words, it's total and complete bull :-) So sorry @Gigili, we won't get an answer out of this...

Comment: The story is not exactly as it is depicted in the current answers, see, e.g., [here](http://www.iaas.uni-bremen.de/sprachblog/2007/04/26/apostrophenschutz/). (I hereby renounce any priviledge to make an answer out of this and invite everybody to do so.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, indeed, the “did” part of the question has so far remained unanswered.

Comment: Sadly, the best information and advice is found in the comments and not the answers to this question.

Comment: evtl. interessant „Füllerzeichen (Filler)“ bei Ursula Bredel (2008): _Die Interpunktion des Deutschen. Ein kompositionelles System zur Online-Steuerung des Lesens._ und — (2009): _Das Interpunktionssystem des Deutschen._ @ Angelika Linke /
Helmuth Feilke: _Oberfläche und Performanz_ 117–135. Beide Tübingen: Niemeyer. [Zusammenfassung von Beatrice Primus (Skript:39ff.)](http://uk-online.uni-koeln.de/remarks/d2/rm2172469.pdf#page=39): „einfache Füller, `-` / `’`, zeigen Defekte innerhalb eines Wortes (…) nicht-horizontale Füller, `…` / `’`, zeigen im Text nicht behebbare Defekte (Auslassungen).“

Answer (score 33, accepted):

German attaches the genitive suffix without an apostrophe.

> Das ist meines Vaters Hut / Das ist der Hut meines Vaters
>
> Der Mann meiner besten Freundin
>
> Julias Mann. Martins Frau.

You will occasionally see " 's " as a genitive ending in German,

> Toni's Imbiss

but that is - to put it mildly - inspired by English orthography, and incorrect in German.

Comment: you might add, that if the name ends with an "s", like Hans, the possessive "s" isn't just added. The car of Hans is: Hansens Auto or Hans' Auto (apostrophe at the end).

Comment: Not to mention "Toni's Imbis's - Alle's mus's rau's"

Comment: The last statement could be misleading since the occasional use of the apostrophe in expressions such as _Andrea’s Boutique_ or _Carlo’s Taverne_ is in accordance with the official rules.

Comment: Only rather recently, and because people have been doing it wrong for so long. The normative power of the factual and all that ...

Comment: @Hinek That exception case is actually not because it is a "possessive apostrophe", but should rather be considered an "Auslassungszeichen". Hans' is "Hansens", as you rightly say, and that "ens" is *omitted*, thus the apostrophe. German does *not* have a possessive apostrophe.

Comment: @Ingmar As far as I know, it was allowed 2002 and was meant to address the question how to handle foreign Names. Are they loan words? Should one treat them as they were German or as in their original language? "Joe's Burger" is explicidly allowed and "Susis Hausmannskost" remains correct. Yes, "Luigi's Pizza" does not support this but still I don't think it was a reaction to misuse but rather to a need of clarification. We Germans love clarity and comprehensive rule sets.

Comment: @tofro there is no ellision. *Hansens* would be northern German, but *Hans'* is High German. I suppose the marking suppletes the morphemic *-s* only because there already is an *s* whereas a double *s* would imply phonetic  shortening of a preceding vowel, e.g. in *Hr. Mus*, *Hr. Muss*. Since English vas the same, *Mr. Mus' car* the comparison here seems apt. Really bust commenting to say that *Hans sein Auto* is proscribed, but possibly one confluence of *Hansens*. Also see *Mutterns*, "Futtern wie bei Muttern".

Comment: i have a big question in mmy mind. can we add "s" as a genitif to all noun?not just person nound. for example. JacksAuto - YaldasFest - WandsFarbe

Answer (score 10):

No, it doesn't. German has a possessive -s without the apostrophe.

> Das ist der Hut meines Vaters.
>
> Der Mann meines besten Freunds.

Using a possessive apostrophe anyway is a fairly common mistake, especially by people whose native language is English, but it's certainly not correct.

Comment: Should read: especially by people who got the main part of their education from RTL and BILD. I doubt that most persons mentioned in advertisings like "Gabi's Nagelcenter", "Petra's Hairstudio" and so on do speak english. BTW, a Deppenapostrophsteuer could save either the Euro or the german language.

Comment: "certainly not correct"... yet.  A prevalent error will become correct.  Okay, maybe not in Germany, but that's how languages *usually* work. ;-)

Comment: @Jürgen: Well, _Willi's Würstchenbude_ is already recorded in the Duden, [see rule 16.2.b)](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/apostroph).

Comment: @Hendrik: so... does that mean what I think it might?  That it's actually... permitted?  There's no explanation for "Willi's" like there is for "Andrea's"...

Comment: @Jürgen: In my opinion it means that the Duden switched to just recording the common mistakes `:-)`

Comment: I never understood what's ambiguous between "Andreas Laden" and "Andreas' Laden"... But too late to change anything, the apostrophe is in every small shop's name ;)

Comment: It is "permitted" for shops to put emphasis on the name. Still looks terrible, though.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Actually, the Duden is committed to recording actual usage of German. So, yes, if a mistake is made sufficiently often by a sufficient number of people, it is adopted by the Duden. That said, Thomas Mann uses the Apostrophe for names ending in a vowel (but not for those ending in a consonant) in Der Zauberberg (1924).

Comment: Mal nebenbei: Seit der Rechtschreibreform sind die Regeln des Dudens nicht mehr offiziell, sondern gewissermaßen nur noch eine private Auslegung der offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln. Dort lautet § 97 E: »Von dem Apostroph als Auslassungszeichen zu unterscheiden ist der gelegentliche Gebrauch dieses Zeichens zur Verdeutlichung der Grundform eines Personennamens vor der Genitivendung *-s* oder vor dem Adjektivsuffix *-sch: Carlo’s Taverne, Einstein’sche Relativitätstheorie«* Es gibt also keine Bedingung der Mehrdeutigkeit.

Answer (score 9):

Your question has already been answered very well. But to add some more information about the meaning of German apostrophe: **In German, an apostrophe is always the hint that *one letter* is missing** (*in direct speech also more than one letters*) even though many people use it in the wrong sense.

### Examples

> Wie geht es: **Wie geht’s**

Explanation: The letter ‘e’ of *es* is missing

> Der Computer gehört Franz/Max/Hans/Maurice *(last "spoken" letter is an s)*:
>   **Es ist Franz’/Max’/Hans’/Maurice’ Computer.**

Explanation: Genitive 's' at the end of the names Franz/Max/Hans/Maurice cannot be pronounced and is therefore replaced with an apostrophe. **Which is indeed an apostrophe at the end of a genitive word. But it has nothing to do with the genitive.** It’s just because one letter is missing.

Comment: "an apostrophe is always the hint that one letter is missing (not two or more!)". I know it's a special case, but how would you write "M'gladbach" and "K'lautern"?

Comment: In written well formed German, an apostrophe is just for **one** missing letter. However, in direct speech (i.e. "spoken" German), an apostrophe can replace **more than one** letter. Read this: [Duden explanation of apostrophes](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/apostroph)

Comment: I did read, and found no indication that rules 13 or 15 do not apply to "written well formed German". Rule 13 explicitly gives the example of _'s_ for _das_.

Comment: Well, at School I learned the one letter rule, it is simple to learn and remember. In 14 they say: "Man **kann** einen Apostroph setzen, wenn Wörter **der gesprochenen Sprache** mit Auslassungen schriftlich wiedergegeben werden und sonst schwer verständlich sind". ***But you are apparently right! Duden is explaining it differently than our teacher.***

Comment: This is non-sense to some degree. *wie geht es* may well be a back-formation from *wie geht es*. I  cannot substantiate my claim any better than this answer does, but compare e.g. Bavarian *seid**s** Ihr deppert?*; *Hört's Ihr?* could be from *es* bjt that would be a peculiar word order. It is simply a Auslaut aspiration that was reinterpreted as morphemic, I suppose.

Answer (score 6):

No, in general the German language does not have an apostrophe in that case.

> Im Gegensatz zum Englischen wird der deutsche Genitiv ohne Apostroph geschrieben. <sup>[DeutscheGrammatik20](http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/attribute/genitiv-namen/)</sup>
>
> Beispiel:
> Englisch: Peter’s house
> Deutsch: Peters Haus

There's one exception to the rule. If the name already ends in an *-s*, an apostrophe is used to indicate the genitive. It's better to reword it, not least because once you read it aloud you lose that indicator.

> Einen Apostroph bekommt der Genitiv im Deutschen nur, wenn der Namen bereits auf –s endet. Hier sollte der Genitiv aber besser durch die Präposition von ersetzt werden.
>
> Beispiel:
> Genitiv mit Apostroph: Klaus‘ Haus
> besser: das Haus von Klaus

There are certain other webpages that summarize that topic. Another trustworthy site is Lingolía. They recognize a second exception:

> Eine weitere Ausnahme besteht, wenn die Grundform von Namen besonders herausgestellt werden soll. Dann ist auch folgende Schreibung erlaubt. <sup>[Lingolia](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/schreibschule/zeichensetzung/apostroph)</sup>
>
> Beispiel: Andrea’s Armbrust

An apostrophe can make an important difference between male Andreas and female Andrea. Example:

> Andreas' Bruder wohnt in Andrea's Haus.

In oral language, there's no distinction whatsoever; but in written language, the apostrophe makes the difference.

For a thorough discussion, I recommend reading [Belles Lettres](http://www.belleslettres.eu/) article about that topic, "[Wann und wie verwendet man den Apostroph](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/apostroph.php)".

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as the genitive apostrophe known in English (*). In German, the genitive "s" is attached without an apostrophe:

> Der Hut meines Vaters
>   Tonys Pommesbude
>   Andreas Friseursalon (it belongs to Andrea)

Only if the noun already ends with a spoken "s"-sound, an apostrophe is **appended** to avoid ambiguity:

> Andreas' Friseursalon (it belongs to Andreas)
>   Franz' Hut

---

(*) The so called "Deppenapostroph" (idiots' apostrophe) exists, mostly to make fun of people who use the English form in German, or even worse things like the famous *Weihnacht'smann* or *Kartoffel'n*.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the answer is yes, the English apostrophe is sometimes adopted.  I came to this conclusion after noticing that my favorite grocery store where I was staying in Königswinter is called “Kaiser's”.

Comment: Kaiser's got its apostrophe before the [orthographic conference of 1901](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Orthographic_Conference_of_1901) and has kept it.