# Did German have a "possessive apostrophe"?

Tags: spelling, history, possessive

There is [an old question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/2550/22043) asking whether contemporary German uses the apostrophe to mark possessive constructions in a way similar to contemporary English – or at least, that's the issue that all the answers address. However, if you read the question carefully, you'll see that the question is also about historical German (my emphasis):

> Does **(did)** German have something like what they call possessive apostrophe in English?

The question is even tagged with the 'history' tag, but this part is not answered by any of the posts. So, I'd like to ask about this aspect explicitly:

Was there **a period in the history of German** during which the apostrophe was either the predominant form or an accepted, frequent alternative to mark the possessive suffix? By "accepted" I loosely mean something like "used in printed works, or used by educated writers".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR

There was a time when the *possessive apostrophe* was accepted.

In the mid-17th century, the apostrophe got a new function. The *Genitiv-Apostroph* (the *possessive apostrophe*) appeared. Its use became widespread in the 18th and 19th century (mostly for personal names). It was used by known authors, in publications (e. g. Goethe's complete works "Goethe's Werke" in 1827) and brands. Even some grammarians approved of it, but it had strong opposition (e. g. Grimm, Duden). The opposition won and by the end of the 19th century it was no longer accepted.

### Resources

**1) Wikipedia**

According to the German wikipedia [article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostroph#Geschichte) on *Apostroph*, there was a period in the 19th century when the *Genitiv-Apostroph* was indeed accepted. The Grimms and Duden were against it, and it fell into disrepute in the late 19th century.

An example given is [Johann Christian August Heyse](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Christian_August_Heyse)'s *Lehrbuch der deutschen Sprache* from 1849:

> Außerdem setzt man den Apostroph auch in dem von persönlichen Eigennamen, besonders Geschlechts- oder Familien-Namen, gebildeten Genitiv vor der Endung ’s, so wie in den von solchen Namen abgeleiteten Adjectiven vor der Adjectiv-Endung, um die richtige Form des Namens deutlicher zu bezeichnen. Z. B. Göthe’s Werke[.]

As can be seen, the apostrophe in the example denotes the Genitive, they are Goethe's works. And here the original, from 1827:

[image: "Goethe's Werke" 1827]
<sub>Johann Wolfgang von Goethe [CC BY-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)]</sub>

Other examples given are brands:

> [Hoffmann’s Stärkefabriken](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoffmann%E2%80%99s_St%C3%A4rkefabriken) (gegründet 1850), [Beck’s Bier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beck%E2%80%99s) (gegründet 1873) oder [Kaiser’s Kaffee Geschäft](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaiser%E2%80%99s_Tengelmann) (gegründet 1880).

**2) Wolf Peter Klein**

Wolf Peter Klein writes in *Kalb’s Leber ist eben frühneuhochdeutsch* in the [FAZ](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/feuilleton/forschung-und-lehre/zur-linguistik-des-genitiv-apostrophs-kalb-s-leber-ist-eben-fruehneuhochdeutsch-12740122.html?printPagedArticle=true#pageIndex_0) 2014:

> Schon im achtzehnten, verstärkt dann im neunzehnten Jahrhundert, ergaben sich Übertragungen auf andere Fälle. Vor allem bei Eigennamen und Toponymen findet man Genitive (Bismarck’s, Mauern Jerusalem’s). Sie wurden sodann gelegentlich auf normale Appellativa übertragen. Schlegel schrieb einen Brief Anfang Mai’s, Fontane wandte sich an den Redakteur des Kunstblatt’s. Etwas später kamen dann noch zwei weitere wichtige Gebrauchsdomänen hinzu, nämlich Abkürzungen und Fremdwörter (des PKW’s, A’s Buch, auf Trainer’s Geheiß).

After its introduction in the 17th century, in the late 18th and more so in the 19th century, the apostrophe saw different usages, also to denote the genitive.

**3) Damaris Nübling**

Interesting is also Damaris Nübling's *Sprachverfall? Sprachliche Evolution am Beispiel  des diachronen Funktionszuwachses des Apostrophs  im Deutschen* 2014, which can be found [here](https://www.germanistik.uni-mainz.de/files/2015/03/Nuebling-2014-Apostroph-IdS-Jahrbuch.pdf). It also shows the development of the apostrophe in German. She writes on p. 103:

> Hinzu kommt ab Mitte des 17. Jahrhunderts ein entscheidender Funktionszuwachs des Apostrophs: Er steht häufig als so genannter Genitivapostroph bei Personennamen (*Amalia’s*), markiert also die Grenze zwischen der Grundform (Nom.Sg.) des Namens und dem Flexiv. Dabei zeigt sich folgende belebtheitsgesteuerte Progression: Personennamen >> Ortsnamen  >>  andere  Namen  und  Appellative  (ebd.,  S.187).

The *Genitiv-Apostroph* appears for the first time in mid-17th century. Nübling notes on p. 104 that contemporaneous grammarians, namely Grimm, Raumer and Duden, rejected this use. But others approved of it. She quotes Sanders, who wrote in 1873:

> Ganz besonders sind hier aber die Eigennamen zu beachten, bei denen es oft von sehr wesentlicher Bedeutung sein kann, sie von den angehängten Flexionstheilen klar und bestimmt geschieden hervortreten zu lassen. Zu diesem Zweck wird dem in der Deklination auftretenden s (gewöhnlich zur Bezeichnung des Genitivs, seltner des Plurals) und dem in der Adjektivbildung auftretenden **sch** ein Apostroph vorgesetzt, vor welchem der unveränderte Eigenname steht. [...] Orthographisch richtig  zu  schreiben  hat  man  also  nach  dem  Vorstehenden  z.B.:  Ein  Gedicht G o e t h e ’s ; Ein G o e t h e ’s c h e s  Gedicht [...].

Nübling further writes

> Tatsächlich sind Apostrophe in Texten des 18. und 19. Jahrhunderts überaus häufig. Ewald (2006, S. 149) listet Beispiele von namhaften Autoren auf  wie von Humboldt (1797), J. Paul (1800), Schiller (1813), eine Zeitung von 1800. Eindeutig dominieren hier die Eigennamen, besonders solche fremder Herkunft und fremder Struktur (z.B. mit auslautenden Vollvokalen): *Galvani’s*, *Creve’s*, *Valli’s*, *Presciani’s*, *Mangili’s*, *Gallini’s*, *Green’s*, *Bilsborrow’s*, *Augusti’s*, *Guerike’s*, *Bell’s*, *Castiglioni’s*, *Gicard’s*, *Coligny’s*, *Katharina’s*, *Beauchamp’s*, *Bobigny’s* etc., aber auch, wenngleich in der Minderzahl, *Lothar’s*, *Heinrich’s*, *Karl’s*.

Not all contemporaneous grammarians loathed the *Genitiv-Apostroph* and it became quite widespread in the 18th and 19th century. As you can see, many well-known authors used it.

Comment: I am not sure if the abuse of the apostroph in company names is a good example for this practice being accepted in the 1850. Company names are the most prominent (ab)use-case of apostrophs even today. In order to prove the practice being accepted in the 1850s, we would need other examples.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I would invert your argument. The fact that there's an abundance of company names with apostrophes shows that it's accepted even today, even if school teachers disagree.

Comment: I think, Thomas Mann used it, too. And for me, when it comes to German language, he's beyond everything any German school teacher will ever tell me :)